# problems with import Azure key vault module in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, azure, single-page-application, azure-keyvault

I got this strange error when importing the keyvault module in JS like this:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I was using the JS single page tutorial.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-javascript-auth-code#use-microsoft-authentication-library-msal-to-sign-in-user

Here is where I imported it.

```
import { DefaultAzureCredential } from "@azure/identity";

import { SecretClient } from "@azure/keyvault-secrets";

const myMSALObj = new msal.PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
```

I would appreciate if some one can point out how to import key vault correctly

Answer (score 0):

You can import **DefaultAzureCredential** and **KeyClient** using the below code -

```
const { DefaultAzureCredential } = require("@azure/identity");
const { KeyClient } = require("@azure/keyvault-keys");
```

Please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/azure/keyvault-keys-readme?view=azure-node-latest#authenticating-with-azure-active-directory) for more details.

Comment: Do you have any idea about the following error: It says that File is a CommonJS module; it may be converted to an ES6 module.

Comment: Does the problem mentioned in question was solved with the code in answer and now you are facing new issues?